# Query for text and return corresponding value, within a date range

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Working on moving an excel sheet to google sheets.
One of the areas I have working quite nicely in excel is finding a paycheck value out of a list of transactions.
The transactions list is a running sheet from 2018.  The current tab has cells `A1` and `A2` specifying the beginning and end days, `ie 7/1/19 7/31/19`.
The formula takes those two dates and searches for the keywords, returns the first, second or third instance (for this formula it's the first)

Trying to figure out how to best move this type of query over to google sheets.
Any advise?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$D$2:$D$8996,SMALL(IF(([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$B$2:$B$8996="DFAS-CLEVELAND   FED SALARY ***********xxxx")+([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$A$2:$A$8996>=$A$1)+([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$A$2:$A$8996<=$A$2)=3,ROW([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$B$2:$B$8996)-ROW(INDEX([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$B$2:$B$8996,1,1))+1),1)),"None")
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
=QUERY(2018!A:B, 
 "select B 
  where A >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and A <= date '"&TEXT(A2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 3", 0)
```

Comment: I can't see to find the option for uploading a file, so here is the sheets link.  Obviously just a snippet.  I only pasted in the area of the sheet where the values are queried/shown. formula I pasted would have been in E1 as an array ( { ) in excel.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xh3720Y-7hA5g3-BDFlKIdpMLchmYFQBIOU2NHwuYIs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Awesome! A couple questions for my understanding if I may.  1st, Can the cell D contents be named differently and still reference a value in sheet1?  Just thinking of cell width.  2nd, can you explain which part of the formula actually updates the E column with the value?  Lastly, I'm looking at the 3rd paycheck field, could you walk me through this last code line?   limit 6 offset 4", 0), {"", "-"; "", "-"})

Comment: see D1 in your sheet. stuff in E column comes from Col4 in formula. {"", "-"; "", "-"} is just an artificial array - see H11 in your sheet

Comment: my apologies, I think I mislead a bit when I listed out the transactions in sheet 1.  this would include all transactions not just ones from DFAS.  So the aim of D1 and D2 in sheet two would be to find the matching text and list the corresponding value. sheet has been updated.

Comment: stuck again.  For the formula in E1, trying to specify the exact text to search for.  If I just put in DFAS it returns a result.  if I enter in even the - for -CLEVELAND it errors out saying empty output. How do you specify an exact string to search for?

Comment: try: `=ArrayFormula(QUERY({Sheet1!A:A,LEFT(Sheet1!B:B,14), Sheet1!C:D}, 
 "select Col2,Col4 
  where Col2 contains 'DFAS-CLEVELAND' 
    and Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 2", 0))`

Comment: still no go.  still need to specify the difference since there are two entries identical except for the last 4 numbers.=ArrayFormula(QUERY({Sheet1!A:A,LEFT(Sheet1!B:B,14), Sheet1!C:D}, "select Col2,Col4 where Col2 contains 'DFAS-CLEVELAND FED SALARY ***********0001' and Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' limit 2", 0))

Comment: getting there. comments added to sheet